# Kendo UI Grid Get Row Values

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to get the row item values (name, email, age) but I'm only able to get the first item by using the code below.

How can I get other row text by changing `tr:eq(1)` code or is there any other way to get two items value?

```
$("#grid_").kendoDropTarget({
    drop: function (e) {
        var data = grid.dataItem("tr:eq(1)");
        // I only get first row but I need to dynamically get any row items.
        alert(data.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

plz try this..

```
var entityGrid = $("#DataGrid").data("kendoGrid");       
var data = entityGrid.dataSource.data();
var totalNumber = data.length;

for(var i = 0; i<totalNumber; i++) {
    var currentDataItem = data[i];
    VersionIdArray[i] = currentDataItem.VersionId;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Thanks Sanjay however I was looking to just select a row items and this is what I got:

```
//Selecting Grid
var gview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
//Getting selected item
var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
//accessing selected rows data 
alert(selectedItem.email);
```

So it worked out perfect.

Comment: can we make it somehow without selecting the row?

Answer (score 4):

if your grid is set to selectable: true, use the following:

```
var mygrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: true
});

mygrid.on("click", "tr", function() {
    var datarowindex = mygrid.data("kendoGrid").items().index(mygrid.data("kendoGrid").select());
    var datarowid = mygrid.data("kendoGrid").dataItem(mygrid.data("kendoGrid").select()).MyId;
    alert("index: " + datarowindex + " | value: " + datarowid);
});
```

if your Kendo UI Grid is set to selectable: false, use the following:

```
var mygrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: false
});

mygrid.on("click", "tr", function() {
    var datarowindex = mygrid.data("kendoGrid").items().index($(this));
    var datarowid = mygrid.data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr")).MyId;
    alert("index: " + datarowindex + " | value: " + datarowid);
});
```

where MyId is the property you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the model from the event. Sometimes, actually very rarely, the row gets deselected and so, the .select() will return a 0 length object which will throw error while trying to access undefined properties.

You might be safer using: `e.model.name`